# How shared memory IPC fits into memory layout of a process?

Tags: linux, shared-memory

Where will the shared memory block of a process be present .Stack segment Heap segment or else where

Answer (score 2):

Shared memory objects are created in a virtual filesystem, normally mounted under /dev/shm. `/dev/shm` is a temporary file storage filesystem, i.e., tmpfs, that uses RAM for the backing store. It will have kernel persistence which means a shared memory object will exist until the system is shut down, or until all     processes have unmapped the object and it has been deleted with `shm_unlink`.